# Making list of objects of class with function overloading

Tags: c++, oop

I am having a class Car, now I want to make linked list of Car objects. So for this I am having a Node class to hold data for each node.

```
class StringOfCar;
class Node
{
    private:
    Node* next;
    Car*  data;
    Node ()
    {
        next = 0;
        data = 0;
    }
    public:
        friend class StringOfCar;
 };
```

And StringOfCar

```
class StringOfCar
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
StringOfCar(){
    head=0;
    tail=0;
}   
void output();
void push (Car &);

};
```

Now I push the elements without any problem with this function :

```
void StringOfCar::push(Car & new_car)
{
    Car  *currentCarPtr;
    Node *currentNodePtr;
    currentNodePtr = new Node;
    currentCarPtr  = new Car(new_car);
    currentNodePtr->next = 0;
    currentNodePtr->data = &new_car;

    if (head == 0)
    {
        head = currentNodePtr;
        tail = currentNodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = currentNodePtr;
        tail       = currentNodePtr;
    }
}
```

But when I try to output, program stops abruptly.I have output() for Car class also. Output function for both class is as follow :

```
void StringOfCar::output(){
    Node * currentNodePtr = head;
    if (head == 0)
        cout << "NO cars \n";
    else
    {   
        while (currentNodePtr != 0)
        {
            currentNodePtr->data->output();
            currentNodePtr = (currentNodePtr->next);
        }
    }
}
```

And for Car class :

```
void Car::output()
{
    cout<<"\nreportingMark "<<setw(3)<<reportingMark;
    cout<<"\ncarNumber "<< setw(8)<< carNumber;
    cout<<"\nkind " << setw(13)<<KIND_ARRAY[kind];
    if (loaded==true)
    {
        cout<<" \nloaded       true";
    }
    else if (loaded == false)
    {
       cout<< "\nloaded       false";
    }
    cout<< "\ndestination "<<setw(7)<<destination<<endl; 
}
```

When I comment currentNodePtr->data->output(); this line, it works fine. What can be problem ? Please help

Comment: You are having problems in the line that prints a `Car` yet you haven't posted the code for `Car`. Without seeing the code for `Car`, it will be hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: ``#include <deque>\ntypedef std::deque<Car> StringOfCar;`` Why is everyone re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Also, post where and how you implemented those functions, might be useful

Comment: @RSahu I posted Car class . Please have a look

Comment: @BitTickler I know it can be done using STL . But please it is not asked here

Comment: @ms8, Your code looks ok at first glance. Try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu I tried avoiding post irrelevent  part of code. But can't reduce it more

Comment: @ms8, where's the `main()` function? What input did you use to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
currentNodePtr->data = &new_car;
```

of the function `void StringOfCar::push(Car & new_car)`.

That should be

```
currentNodePtr->data = currentCarPtr;
```